# How can I calculate in SVG coordinates?

Tags: html, css, svg, line, coordinates

Given a simple SVG containing a line of some width from top left to bottom right.

```
<svg><line x1="0px" y1="0px" x2="100%" y2="100%"
style="stroke: #aaa; stroke-width: 6px"/></svg>
```

The line gets positioned amd stretched with CSS. Since it always spans the whole SVG, I can just set width and height of the SVG to do so. The problem is that edges of the line get cut in the corners.

[image: SVG line with cut off edges]

Since I want to see the whole line including its corners. I thought about adding which is twice the stroke width to the SVG size. Then the line could start at 6px from left and top and go to 100% - 6px. How can I express this calculated coordinates in SVG? I would need something like the `calc()` in CSS3.

Comment: Feels like this will require a js solution.

Comment: @Paulie_D How can I modify the line coordinates from JS?

Comment: Oh...I'm no expert but it's seems like the only way I can think of.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm fine with that. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Nope...but I'm sure google could help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding id="lineId" to your html element, and then in js:

```
<html>
<body onload="resizeLine();">

<svg width="500px" height="150px"><line id="lineId" x1="6px" y1="6px" x2="100%" y2="100%"
style="stroke: #aaa; stroke-width: 6px"/></svg>

<script>
function resizeLine() {
    alert('Note that line is not resized yet.');
    var line = document.getElementById('lineId'),
        lineWidth = line.getBoundingClientRect().width,
        lineHeight = line.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    line.setAttribute('x2', lineWidth-6);
    line.setAttribute('y2', lineHeight-6);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you demo this please..for my education?

Comment: Apologies bit I can't seem to get that to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/fQF32/3/ Am I missing something?

Comment: It would work as a html file. For jsfiddle you need that form: http://jsfiddle.net/fQF32/4/